# ExtJS 4.2 - Refresh grid with current variable store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a gridpanel on a panel window that loads a certain store:

```
xtype: 'gridpanel',
  store: custStore,
  viewConfig: {
    loadMask: false,
    enableTextSelection: true
  },
  hideHeaders: false,
  bodyBorder: true,
  id: 'playerslist-grid-id',
  itemId: 'playerslist-grid-id',
  viewConfig: {
    deferEmptyText: false,
    emptyText: 'No records yet'
  },
  columns: [{
    text: 'Customer',
    dataIndex: 'username',
    flex: 1
  }, {
    header: '',
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    itemId: 'remove-player-btn',
    width: 50,
    sortable: false,
    resizable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    hidden: bHide,
    items: [{
      icon: 'resources/img/x.png',
      tooltip: 'Remove Player',
      scope: oMe
    }],
    editor: {
      xtype: 'text',
      name: 'deleteRow'
    }
  }]
```

The `custStore` variable is handled like this.

```
var oMe = this;
oController = EcommBackoffice.Global.app_var.getController('CustomerTagsController'),
  cStore = oController.getCustomerListStore(),
  cDetails = cStore.first(),
  customers = [];

customers = cDetails.get('customers');

var custStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
  model: 'CustomerList',
  data: customers
});
```

I needed to put it in an array store as the data object is nested like so:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'test',
  description: 'test',
  customers: [{
    id: 001,
    username: 'bob'
  }, {
    id: 001,
    username: 'terese'
  }, {
    id: 001,
    username: 'dab'
  }, {
    id: 001,
    username: 'bba'
  }, {
    id: 001,
    username: 'hello'
  }]
}
```

On my controller I process a function that places `custStore` to it and other parameters before a `request`.

```
click: function() {
  oController.addPlayerToTag(newPlayer, tagId, custStore);
}
```

**Problem**: How do I reload `custStore` on the `gridpanel` I'm on after a successful callback? I tried using `custStore.load()` but nothing happened.

Comment: have you tried custStore.reload()?

Comment: Yes. That did not work as well. It seems that the store is being reloaded but the actual view of the `gridpanel` is not. I just want to be clear that the `.reload()` is being done from the controller function as called by the `detailPanel` view. Seems that the `gridpanel` on the `detailPanel` view is not updating regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you get a new array of customers back from the server and need to refresh the grid with that array. In that case I think you need to call [setData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-setData) on the custStore, passing in the new array of customers. Not sure if 4.2 has this method. If not, try setting custStore.data property.

If that alone doesn't work, try also calling [reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-reconfigure) on the grid, passing in the custStore.